# Why is localization not working on Android?

Tags: android, xml, localization

I am trying to create a spanish localization directory for landscape mode.

However, it seems to be defaulting to the regular strings.xml in layout-es.xml.

I named the directory layout-es-land.

I do not understand why is it not using layout-es-land when I rotate the device.

Comment: You say you name the directory name as `layout-es-land.xml`. Tried directory name without .xml? That seems to be the name of the layout file not directory.

If your layout is same for both of the languages, then probably you can just have different strings in strings.xml in `res/values` and `res/values-es` directoy.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part, I did not name the directory with a .xml. Also, I am trying to display different text depending on if the device is rotated or not. That's why I created `res/layout-land`. So putting my `strings.xml` for landscape in `values-es` would to work unfortunately